# Why the vue-router do not work?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my `main.js`, I have a `router`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

// config the router
const router = new VueRouter({
  routers: [
    {path: '/home', component: Home},
    {path: '/helloworld', component: HelloWorld},
  ],
  mode: "history"
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),   
})
```

My `App.vue` code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        helth: 100,
        ended: false
      }
    },

  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The `HelloWorld.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Home
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default{
    data(){
      return {msg: 'hello vue'}
    },
    components: {}
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The `HelloWorld.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default{
    data(){
      return {msg: 'hello vue'}
    },
    components: {}
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

But in my browser, there do not show anything, no matter the `x/home` or `x/helloworld`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**EDIT**

I try to access this link:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8081/Home.vue
```

But I get bellow error in my page:

> Cannot GET /Home.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `routers` to `routes`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
 routes: [ // <<< here
    {path: '/home', component: Home},
    {path: '/helloworld', component: HelloWorld},
  ],
  mode: "history"
})
```

Answer (score -1):

can you try accessing using the URL

http://0.0.0.0:8081/Home.vue

http://0.0.0.0:8081/helloworld.vue

regards,

Raghu

Comment: I get `Cannot GET /Home.vue`.